# Add value on one column based on values of a group of rows

Tags: postgresql

Imagine something like "uber Eats":

there is a driver's base (mall), other restaurants outside the mall and customers locations.

Each row is a travel between two points (base, restaurant_# and customer #)   : can have services with 3 rows (base-restaurant-customer-base) other with 2 (base-customer-base), other with a little more.... (wrong order :)) of fuel stop.

**Need to aggregate for each service the rows applicable to that service in a column**, for example service_numb with a serial number starting each month and the month,  1/month,2/month ,3/month.

there is a column:

- Base, where "OUT" and "IN" indicate leaving base and returning base,
  so this should be the trigger for a new service.
- dateline, for sequencing/order
- cart, for identifying the delivering cart, among many

this is only to be run one time to populate that column, instead of doing it manually.

is possible in **postgresSQL 13.6**  ?

**EDIT:**

With a table:

| datetime | cart | base |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 08 23 10:10 | aa | OUT |
| 2022 08 23 10:20 | aa |  |
| 2022 08 23 10:30 | aa | IN |
| 2022 08 23 10:05 | bb | OUT |
| 2022 08 23 10:10 | bb |  |
| 2022 08 23 10:30 | bb |  |
| 2022 08 23 10:35 | bb | IN |
| 2022 09 23 10:10 | aa | OUT |
| 2022 09 23 10:20 | aa |  |
| 2022 09 23 10:30 | aa | IN |

needed to create an additional column with the service number, year/month and by cart, like:

| datetime | cart | base | service_num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 08 23 10:10 | aa | OUT | aa/202208/1 |
| 2022 08 23 10:20 | aa |  | aa/202208/1 |
| 2022 08 23 10:30 | aa | IN | aa/202208/1 |
| 2022 08 23 10:05 | bb | OUT | bb/202208/1 |
| 2022 08 23 10:10 | bb |  | bb/202208/1 |
| 2022 08 23 10:30 | bb |  | bb/202208/1 |
| 2022 08 23 10:35 | bb | IN | bb/202208/1 |
| 2022 09 23 10:10 | aa | OUT | aa/202209/1 |
| 2022 09 23 10:20 | aa |  | aa/202209/1 |
| 2022 09 23 10:30 | aa | IN | aa/202209/1 |

**EDIT2:**

```
SELECT *,SUM(CASE WHEN base='OUT' then 1 end) OVER (PARTITION BY cart ORDER BY datetime) AS m1
FROM table
ORDER BY datetime
```

already gives a sequential number across all the table, divided by cart.

missing:
add cart, yyyy/mm and restart the numbering each month and by cart

**EDIT3:**

using the provided answer below by @Andriy M, is already working, the only issue is in the cases where one or more of the legs "jump" to the next month?

example:
leg1 2022/07/31 23:30
leg2 2022/08/01 00:05
leg3 2022/08/01 00:35

for the same service_number.
The datetime, is already timeline, so no issue there. The question seems to be on the PARTITION BY of the datetime, to accomodate the passage to a new month.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Where does the service number come from?

Comment: "service number" is the objective...  with the code of EDIT2, have a column with 1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3 for that table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `service_num` values seem to consist of these three components delimited by a `/`:

- `cart`;
- expression representing the month of `datetime` formatted as `YYYYMM`;
- expression enumerating OUT/IN sequences.

Nothing needs to be done about `cart`, you just use it in the final concatenation expression.

Regarding the formatted month, you can obtain it as

```
to_char(datetime, 'YYYYMM')
```

And as for the sequence numbers, your `SUM` expression is a good start.  You need to additionally partition by months in order for the numbers to reset each month.  You can use the above month expression as the second partition criterion:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN base='OUT' THEN 1 END)
OVER (PARTITION BY cart, to_char(datetime, 'YYYYMM') ORDER BY datetime)
```

Or you could use the `date_trunc` function instead, which might or might not be faster:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN base='OUT' THEN 1 END)
OVER (PARTITION BY cart, date_trunc('month', datetime) ORDER BY datetime)
```

With all the components now covered, you just need to concatenate them into a single `service_num` value:

```
SELECT
  *
, cart
  || '/'
  || to_char(datetime, 'YYYYMM')
  || '/'
  || SUM(CASE WHEN base='OUT' THEN 1 END)
     OVER (PARTITION BY cart, date_trunc('month', datetime) ORDER BY datetime)
  AS service_num
FROM
  YourTable
ORDER BY
  datetime
;
```

Comment: thanks, it works. Any idea how to cover the case when one or more of the legs "jump" to the next month?   ex:  leg1  2022/07/31 23:30   leg2  2022/08/01  00:05  leg3  2022/08/01  00:35, for the same service_number.  The datetime, is allready timeline, so no issue there. The question seems to be on the `PARTITION BY` of the datetime,

Comment: @domiho1: Not at the moment, no.  If I did have one, it would be better to post it as a separate solution to a separate question though, so as not to turn this one into a mess.  (If/when you decide to submit this as a new question, please make sure to explain what you want the output for such cases to look like.)

Comment: thanks. will make a EDIT3 above, to accommodate the month pass issue, as is directly related to the initial request

Comment: @domiho1: I think this question is good as it is.  Your additional stipulation makes it a new problem really, even if related to the original one.  Therefore, it would be better to create a new thread instead of editing this question.

Comment: done in https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/316015/group-of-rows-evaluated-when-passing-to-next-month. thanks!