# Populate rows based on values of previous row and rows group

Tags: postgresql

with **postgresSQL 13.6**

Following the question from here [Add value on one column based on values of a group of rows](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/315911/add-value-on-one-column-based-on-values-of-a-group-of-rows).

with rows grouped per service_num, is possible to populate the remaining row of that group, using the same text already included in one of those rows.

with the table:

| datetime | cart | base | service_num | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 08 23 10:10 | aa | OUT | aa/202208/1 |  |
| 2022 08 23 10:20 | aa |  | aa/202208/1 |  |
| 2022 08 23 10:30 | aa | IN | aa/202208/1 | corporate |
| 2022 08 23 10:05 | bb | OUT | bb/202208/1 |  |
| 2022 08 23 10:10 | bb |  | bb/202208/1 | private |
| 2022 08 23 10:30 | bb |  | bb/202208/1 |  |
| 2022 08 23 10:35 | bb | IN | bb/202208/1 |  |
| 2022 09 23 10:10 | aa | OUT | aa/202209/1 |  |
| 2022 09 23 10:20 | aa |  | aa/202209/1 | other |
| 2022 09 23 10:30 | aa | IN | aa/202209/1 |  |

populate like this:

| datetime | cart | base | service_num | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 08 23 10:10 | aa | OUT | aa/202208/1 | corporate |
| 2022 08 23 10:20 | aa |  | aa/202208/1 | corporate |
| 2022 08 23 10:30 | aa | IN | aa/202208/1 | corporate |
| 2022 08 23 10:05 | bb | OUT | bb/202208/1 | private |
| 2022 08 23 10:10 | bb |  | bb/202208/1 | private |
| 2022 08 23 10:30 | bb |  | bb/202208/1 | private |
| 2022 08 23 10:35 | bb | IN | bb/202208/1 | private |
| 2022 09 23 10:10 | aa | OUT | aa/202209/1 | other |
| 2022 09 23 10:20 | aa |  | aa/202209/1 | other |
| 2022 09 23 10:30 | aa | IN | aa/202209/1 | other |

the type wording may appear in any of the rows of each group.

i'm trying to use `lag` expression with only replicate what is on the previous row on select column

Comment: Create a https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13 with the sample data above and update your post with the url

Comment: Can't you just update each group with the max or min value for the group?

Comment: thanks, will explore that https://dbfiddle.uk/ . Max value of the group seems to work just fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it you can update each group with the max or min value for that group:

```
UPDATE t t1
    SET type = (SELECT MAX(type) 
                FROM t t2 
                WHERE t2.service_num = t1.service_num);
```

Untested.

You may concider moving type to a separate table (since it seems to be dependent of a non key attribute in your current table)

```
CREATE TABLE service_num_type  -- Or whatever this may be 
( service_num text not null primary key
, type text not null -- type is a reserved world
);

INSERT INTO service_num_type
    (service_num, type)
SELECT DISTINCT service_num, type
FROM t
WHERE type is not null;

ALTER TABLE t
    DROP COLUMN type;

ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT <constraint name>
    FOREIGN KEY (service_num)
    REFERENCES service_num_type
                (service_num);
```

Comment: thanks! the Max value seems to work really well - it takes some time (10sec) but this query is only to populate that column.

Comment: while not fully understand the concept of moving it to a separate table, the initial "type" input is made by hand - could build some automatedly, but many needs to human input to avoid what seems over complicated query to find the type of "type".  Having all columns in a single table is seems easier to understand the "type" to be input. a view could be an option, but struggle to make input while on a view.

Comment: With your current design you could end up in a situation where someone updates the type for one row - say - aa/202208/1 to corporate and another person updates another row for the same service_num to private.